# jQuery load(), then use hide() on what's loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading a series of `<li>`s and would then like to hide all but the first 9... I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myList").load("tweet-list.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
        $("#myList").load('tweet-list.php', function() {
            $('#myList li:gt(8)').hide();
        });
    }, 120000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

But I cannot get the `$('#myList li:gt(8)').hide();` part to work, and so the entire file shows... I imagine I need to use .live() but I'm not sure what event to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to use setInterval. Just provide a callback to load which will be called once your list is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend loading them as hidden, and then explicitly showing the ones you want to see.  The  `.hide()` function runs asynchronously, and you could end up with some weirdness.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myList li').filter(function(){ return $(this).index()>8; }).hide();
```

for example